# Rate equation for a reaction involving a polymer having absorbed small proteins according to langmuir's model

Tags: kinetics, absorption

First, let me apologize for the awful question title..

I have a solution with polymers with $N$ binding sites and small proteins, which can attach to a binding site. The polymers will absorb the proteins till $N^*$ out of $N$ sites are occupied. From that moment the polymer can undergo a certain structural deformation and will drop some small proteins in the process.

My problem is this: I would like to write down the rate equations of the problem and I thought that langmuir's model would be a good way to describe the absorption of the proteins to a polymer. However, this theory gives the rate of the surface decomposition $\theta$, but I would like to be able to let the polymer undergo the deformation reaction (involving the concentration of polymers having absorbed $N^*$ proteins). How can I incorporate the langmuir model in the "ordinary" set of first order rate equations? How can I get to a numerically solvable system of equations that describe the kinetics of this problem having so many absorbing surfaces (i.e. polymers)?
In other words, is there a way to obtain the concentration of polymers having a certain $\theta$?